# Only in iOS 14 , my uiwebview crash in stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString

Tags: ios, objective-c

In UIWebview, when I call  stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:  the second time, the program crashes, which only happens in iOS 14, do you have this question? Is UIWebview updated in IOS 14? What should we do?

Comment: Why are you still using `UIWebView` in 2020?

Comment: We will use WKWebview in later versions

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour], read [ask] and update your question with a [example].

Comment: iOS 14 is not officially released; it could just be a beta bug.  Report it to Apple.